# Error "Could not resolve container" in Awilix

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs

I know that error says it all, but I am actually not that good with Awilix.

Here's my loader/index.js:

```
export default () => {
    const container = createContainer();

    container.loadModules([
        ['services/*.js', { register: asClass }],
        ['controllers/routes/*.js', { register: asClass }],
        ['global-controllers/*.js', { register: asFunction }]
    ], {
            formatName: 'camelCase',
            resolverOptions: {
                lifetime: Lifetime.SINGLETON
            }
        });

    container.register({
        apiController: asFunction(apiController).singleton(),
        schemas: asFunction(schemas)
    });

    container.register({
        errors: asValue(errors),
        Sequelize: asValue(Sequelize),
        context: asFunction(context)
    });

    return container;
};
```

And here's I use it:

```
export default async (container) => {
    await container.resolve('context').sequelize.sync({ force: true });

    const app = express();

    app.use('/static', express.static(join(__dirname, './api/views/')));
    app.use(cookieParser(key));
    app.use(json());

    app.use('/api', container.resolve('cacheGlobal'));
    app.use('/api', container.resolve('apiController'));
    app.use('/api', container.resolve('errorGlobal'));

    return app;
}
```

The full error message is:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: AwilixResolutionError: Could not resolve 'cacheGlobal'."

I thought maybe it was name resolving problem I tried several ways and once it worked! Almost, the Router.use() got object and it still crashed.

Answer (score 2):

Yep, it was a path related issue, just had to change this:

```
['services/*.js', { register: asClass }],
['controllers/routes/*.js', { register: asClass }],
['global-controllers/*.js', { register: asFunction }]
```

To this:

```
['./api/services/*.js', { register: asClass }],
['./api/controllers/routes/*.js', { register: asClass }],
['./api/global-controllers/*.js', { register: asFunction }]
```